# put the logical decision in the controller or in the view

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In my application user can create post,however only the creator of the post can delete it.

So I have to make the decision for each post when I list them.

Then which is better to to this logic decision,in the controller or in the view?

Now I do it in the view:

**Controller:**

```
class PostController{
  @RequestMapping("post/list")
  public void list(Model m){
   List<Post> posts=queryPosts();
   m.addAttribute(posts);
  }
}
```

**post_list.ftl**

```
<#list ${posts} as post>
  <span>${post.name}</span>
  <#if ${post.owner}==${session.user}>
    <a href="post/${post.id}/delete">Delete</a>
  </#if>
</#list>
```

Then I want to know if this is the best practice?

If put the logic decesion in the controller is better,then how to make it? Add an `editable` field of the Post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final decision and logic about what item can be deleted by which user should be made in the controller. Ironically, from what I can see in your code this is actually what is happening - you are just making the determination about wether to show the delete link in your UI, based off the current user - which is fine in my opinion.

Comment: `The final decision... in the controller`,then you say `making the determination about wether to show the delete link in your UI....is fine in my opinion.` I am not exactly sure your meaning.

Comment: @hguser - Your current code is fine, it does not actually have delete logic on the UI side. It has presentation logic for determining when to show the delete ***link***. Nothing wrong with that imo.

Answer (score 2):

The decision must ultimately be made in the controller. What would otherwise happen if a malicious user tried accessing the `delete` page?

However it's good practice in the view to only let users see links to pages they have access to.

`Spring Security` offers multiple approaches to protecting URLs or routines based on user, role or group.

Comment: In fact,even I do the decision in the controller,when a url 'post/1/delete' is send from the client,I will also check angin if the user have the permission.\